# Internet Explorer 9 opens ajax URL instead of sending data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

this simple ajax call works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari :

```
function downloadEntryReport() {
    var data_range = document.getElementById("daterange").value;
    var ajax_url = "ajaxcalls/download_entry_report/"+data_range;

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error loading document');
            return false;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            document.location.href = "ajaxcalls/download_entry_report/"+data_range;
        }
    });
}
```

except in IE (tested in 9.0.8). IE opens the URL (ajaxcalls/download_entry_report/given_date_range) which of course returns a 404 error. Is there a hack around this issue in IE or am I missing something?
Appreciate your help!

Here's the called PHP function :

```
function download_entry_report($data_range) {
        $date_range_array = explode("%20::%20", $data_range);
        $start_date = $date_range_array[0];
        $end_date = $date_range_array[1];

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE created_by = '".$this->session->userdata('email')."' AND DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."' ");
        $results = $query->result_array();

        echo $this->download_csv_results($results, 'entry_report.csv');
        exit();
    }
```

and the other function to download the csv file :

```
function download_csv_results($results, $name = NULL)
    {
        if( ! $name)
        {
            $name = md5(uniqid() . microtime(TRUE) . mt_rand()). '.csv';
        }

        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $name);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Expires: 0");

        $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");

        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            fputcsv($outstream, $result);
        }

        fclose($outstream);
    }
```

Comment: When you set the `document.location.href` you are asking to redirect to a new page ... what are you expecting ?

Comment: I suppose I should have posted the called PHP file so you can see it clean : please have a look above (post edited)

Comment: Oops ... not a PHP expert here .. just saw the PHP Tag ... My Bad.

Comment: Configure your default document for that folder on your server or use a fully qualified uri... eg../path/index.php